# Cordova Geolocation onError not working

Tags: cordova, geolocation

Can get the geolocation plugin to work fine aslong as the user gives permission to track their location.

If the user denies permission the onError function does not get called does anyone know a reason for this?

```
render: function() {

        var compiledTemplate = _.template( template, {
          webfeatures: this.collection.models,
          accessToken: App.api.config.access_token
        });
        this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
        $("#webfeatures").trigger("create");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
        console.log('webfeature rendered');

    },

    onSuccess: function(position) {
        console.log(position);  
    },


    onError: function(PositionError) {
        console.log(PositionError);
    }
```

I want to be able to show a message to customers if they don't allow geolocation to track their location some of the features of the app will not work.

Comment: I had the same issue but still didn't solve it